# Moving the position of a text block in tikzposter

Tags: positioning, tikzposter

this is my first time using tikzposter and I am trying to move the position of one of my text blocks upward to free up some more space on my poster but I am unsure how. I have had a look at the tikzposter documentation but I can't see anything in there about changing the x,y position of the text block on the poster. I'll add an image below of what it looks like.

[image: Image of my poster with the large gap between blocks]

What I am trying to do is get rid of that big vertical spacing between the tech used block and the future work block but I can't work out how to do it. Does anyone have a method of doing this?

```
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.6}
    \block{Technology Used}{\blindtext[1]}
    \column{0.4}
    \block{Work Done}{\blindtext[1]}
        \column{0.5}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
    
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Future Work}{}
\end{columns}
```

The above Latex code is how I am getting them to load onto the PDF

Thank you in advance for any help anyone gives me.

Comment: Move Future Work block after Technology Used block. If you declare it inside a new `columns` environment, it will be placed below the previous columns environment like it happens now.

Comment: I have moved the future work into the same environment as the tech used and work done but the future work block does not show up at all then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `columns` environment is placed below the previous one. As `Future work` block is inside a second `columns` environment, it's placed below the first one. If `Future work` is move to the first `columns`environment just after `Technology used` block, the vertical space will disapear.

Following code shows three `columns` environments, first and second are the originals and the third is the "correct" one.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
     blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter} %Default values for poster format options.

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.6}
    \block{Technology Used}{\blindtext[1]}
    \column{0.4}
    \block{Work Done}{\blindtext[1]}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Future Work}{}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.6}
    \block{Technology Used}{\blindtext[1]}
    \block{Future Work}{}
    \column{0.4}
    \block{Work Done}{\blindtext[1]}
        \column{0.5}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]